# Find the value of $ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{\int_{1}^{3}x^{n/x} dx}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the value of $ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{\int_{1}^{3}x^{n/x} dx}$.

My attempt:

$$ L = (\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{1}^{3} x^{\frac {n}{x}}\mathrm{d}x)^\frac {1} {n} \Longrightarrow \log L = \frac {\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{1}^{3} x^{\frac{n}{x}}\mathrm{d}x} {n}$$

Using L'H$\hat{\mathrm{o}}$pital's rule,

$ \Longrightarrow \log L = \frac {\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac {\int_{1}^{3} \log x x^{\frac{n}{x}} \mathrm{d}x} {x}} {\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{1}^{3} x^{\frac{n}{x}}\mathrm{d}x} = \frac {L \log 3} {3} $

Comparing $\frac {\log 3}{3} = \frac {\log L}{L}$,

$ L = 3$.

But the given answer is $ e^{1/e}$.

Comment: You are mixing up variables. $x$ is  a variable of integration and the limit is not w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $M=\max \; |f(x)|$, is $M=\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} \left(\int_a^b|f(x)|^n\,\mathrm dx\right)^{1/n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88300/if-fx-is-continuous-on-a-b-and-m-max-fx-is-m-lim-limits-n)