# How to find the limit $\left (\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^n xdx\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: integration, limits, beta-function

This is equivalent to $\left (\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2n!!}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$. I try to add some terms to the denominator, so as to use the Stirling formula. Then
$$\left (\frac{((2n-1)!!)^2}{2n!}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
is also hard to go on. The form of this integral seems to be applicable to the Hölder inequality, but I can’t find the appropriate $p$ and $q$ such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Does anyone have a good idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that $(2n)!!=2^n n!$, hence $$\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}=\frac{(2n)!}{(2^nn!)^2}.$$Now you can use Stirling's formula.  Alternatively, we have the [general result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88300/if-fx-is-continuous-on-a-b-and-m-max-fx-is-m-lim-limits-n).

Comment: This is a special case of [If $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $M=\max \; |f(x)|$, is $M=\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} \left(\int_a^b|f(x)|^n\,\mathrm dx\right)^{1/n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/88300/42969)

Comment: We can use the fact that if $a_n>0$ and $a_{n+1}/a_n\to L$ then $a_{n} ^{1/n}\to L$.

Comment: I am sorry ! I had a mistake. Fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $\sin(x) \ge 2x/\pi$ on $[0,\pi/2]$. Hence
$$
\frac{\pi}{2(n+1)} = \int_0^{\pi/2}(2x/\pi)^n dx \le \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^n dx \le \frac{\pi}{2}.
$$
Thus
$$
\left(\frac{\pi}{2(n+1)}\right)^{1/n} \le \left(\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^n dx\right)^{1/n} \le  \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{1/n},
$$
which yields
$$
\left(\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^n dx\right)^{1/n} \to 1 \quad (n \to\infty).
$$

Answer (score 2):

Using
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^n (x)\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \,\,\Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{2 \,\Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)}$$
Take  logarithms and use twice Stirling approximation
$$\log\left ( \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^n (x)\,dx  \right)=\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{\pi }{2 n}\right)-\frac{1}{4
   n}+\frac{1}{24 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$

Divide by $n$ and use Taylor since
$$a=e^{\log(a)}$$

$$\left (\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^n( x)\,dx\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=1+\frac{\log \left(\frac{\pi }{2 n}\right)}{2 n}+\frac{\log
   ^2\left(\frac{\pi }{2 n}\right)-2}{8 n^2}+\cdots$$ which is in a relative error smaller than $0.01$% as soon as $n>10$ and smaller than $0.001$% as soon as $n>15$

Answer (score 2):

The $\exp$ in front contains the integral,
$$\begin{align*}a_n&=\exp\frac{1}{n}\log\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^n(x)\ dx\\&=\exp\frac{1}{n}\log\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \exp\left({n\log(\sin x)}\right)\ dx \\
&\sim\exp\frac{1}{n}\log\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}-\varepsilon}^{\frac{\pi}{2}+\varepsilon}\exp\left({n\log(\sin x)}\right)\ dx \\
&=\exp\frac{1}{n}\log\int_{-\varepsilon}^{\varepsilon}\exp\left({n\log(\cos t)}\right)\ dt \\
&\sim\exp\frac{1}{n}\log\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon \exp\left({n\log\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^4}{24}\right)}\right)\ dt \\
&\sim\exp\frac{1}{n}\log\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon\exp\left(-\frac{nt^2}{2}-\frac{nt^4}{12}\right)\ dt \\
&\sim\exp\frac{1}{n}\log\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon \exp\left(-\frac{nt^2}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{nt^4}{12}\right)\ dt \\
&\sim\exp\frac{1}{n}\log\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{nt^2}{2}\right)\ dt \tag{leading order} \\
&=\exp\frac{1}{n}\log2\int_{0}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{nt^2}{2}\right)\ dt \\
&=\exp\frac{1}{n}\log\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 n}}\int_0^\infty\exp(-s^2)\ ds \\
&=\exp\frac{1}{n}\log\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n}} \\
&=\sqrt{\frac{\pi^{1/n}}{(2n)^{1/n}}}
\end{align*}$$
as $n\to\infty$, where I made the following substitutions:
$$x=t+\frac{\pi}{2},\quad s^2=\frac{nt^2}{2}.$$
The limit is then,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

The exact formula for the Wallis integral is in general not very useful for asymptotic calculus. It is in general better to use $\displaystyle W_n = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^n(x) \, dx \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n}}$. This equivalent is actually used to prove the Stirling formula.

You deduce that $\frac{\ln(W_n)}{n} \sim \frac{\ln(\pi/2n)}{2n} \rightarrow 0$ thus $W_n^{1/n} \rightarrow 1$.